# Redirect AngularJS up one directory

Tags: angularjs

Im using Angular.js and I have several routes:

```
http://localhost/tool/new
http://localhost/tool/report/#/59FD59D56F20DDFA722F5B31796CAE3396C
```

tool/new is the form where a user would create a new report using the tool. The program then runs in the background and the user can access the report by going to tool/report/#/their-id where their-id is a big SHA1 hash.

That hash is a route param, if that hash is invalid I need to redirect the user back to tool/new. The problem Im having is that the program file structure is:

```
tool/new/index.html // The create new report form
tool/report/index.html // The report area
```

I've been trying to use $location to redirect like this:

```
$location.path('/new');
```

But it just redirects to tool/report/#/new and that doesn't help.

Does anyone know how to tell Angular to move up one directory and redirect?

---

Based on the answer from Branimir, I get the URL and trim it at the current (report) directory. I do this because the tool name and domain can change depending on the server its located on. This worked for me.

```
var dialog = $dialogs.notify('We were unable to find your tool run.','<p>It is possible that the URL you have entered is incorrect or that your tool run has been deleted due to inactivity.</p><p>Please confirm your URL and try again; or create a new tool run.</p>');
dialog.result.then(function(btn){
   var url = $location.absUrl();
   var base = url.substring(0,url.indexOf('/report/'));
   window.location = base + '/#/new';
},function(btn){});
```

Note Im using $dialogs from here https://github.com/m-e-conroy/angular-dialog-service/blob/master/dialogs.min.js to tell the user the id is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reload page use:

```
$window.location.href = 'http://localhost/tool/new';
```

$location service doesn't reload a page, it changes a URL in the same AngularJS application.